# export JSON file from index file in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

in my typescript project, i am able to re-export my default exports in index.ts of a folder.

for eg:

```
export { default as BaseError } from "./errorResponse";
```

but i am unable to export JSON files like this.

```
export * as configFiles from "./config";
```

how to bundle and export JSON files such that i can use it in paths of tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@errorClass": ["src/helpers/errorClasses"],
      "@config": ["src/config"],
      "@routes": ["src/routes"]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add the following options inside your `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

After updating `tsconfig` file export configFile like below:

```
export { default as configFiles } from "./config.json";
```

Now to import the `configFiles` inside your code use below:

```
import { configFiles } from "./file-path-to-configFiles-variable";

console.log(configFiles);
```

Comment: `export { default as configFiles } from "./config.json";` yes but where should this code live?

Comment: @milosmns that code goes within an index.ts file where you have your json file present; so if you have config.json at ./someDir then you will also have index.ts at ./someDir/index.ts with that export

Answer (score 0):

example **tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        ...
        "paths": {
            "@config":["src/config/*"],
         ...
        },`
```

```
import { xConfig } from '@config/index';
```